# Why is this SELECT taking 2-3 minutes and how could I reduce it down to a few seconds?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
select to_date(checks.payment_dte, 'YYYYMMDD') as payment_date,
       checks.run_number, 
       checks.check_nbr as check_number, 
       checks.check_amt as check_amount, 
       checks.payee_no as payee_number, 
       checks.loc as location, 
       checks.fac_state as facility_state, 
       checks.delta_usa_ind, 
       checks.payee_lnme as payee_last_name, 
       checks.payee_fnme as payee_first_name, 
       checks.payee_addr1 as payee_address1, 
       checks.payee_addr2 as payee_address2, 
       checks.payee_addr3 as payee_address3, 
       checks.payee_city, 
       checks.payee_st as payee_state, 
       to_char(checks.payee_zip, '00000') as payee_zip,
       to_char(checks.payee_zip4, '0000') as payee_zip4, 
       checks.payee_country_cde as payee_country_code,
       country.country_abbreviation as payee_country_code_description, 
       checks.maint_code as maintenance_code, 
       checks.mod_dte as mod_date, 
       checks.mod_op, 
       checks.payment_profile_id, 
       checks.bank_profile_id, 
       checks.parent_id
from (select c.*, 
             check_total
      from db1.tbl_payment_checks c
      join (select sum(net) as check_total, 
                   check_nbr
            from (select nvl(sum(total_net),0) net, 
                         check_nbr
                  from db1.tbl_wip_hist_header
                  group by check_nbr
                  union all
                  select nvl(sum(refund_amount)*-1,0) net, 
                         check_number check_nbr
                  from db1.tbl_payment_refund_header
                  group by check_number)
            group by check_nbr) sums on (c.check_nbr = sums.check_nbr)
      where payee_no = '840932794'
      order by payment_dte desc) checks
left join db1.tbl_code_country country
             on (checks.payee_country_cde = country.country)
where rownum < 10
order by payment_dte desc
```

Comment: It's likely that your multiple joins and union are slowing down the query execution.

Comment: Without digging into the guts, my first thought would be materialized view as this seems like its a once a day thing and you don't need to worry about transactions in the pipeline. (I get this from the fact there's a "RUN Number" and the materialized view could be set to update once the "RUN" is done.

Comment: Where is payee_no found? You are likely doing a Full Table Scan of each table that is participating in the UNION. What does the query plan look like? What indexes are available? Can the filter on payee_no be applied in each part of the UNION?

Comment: Have you looked at the query execution plan via an `explain`?

Comment: @JackManey Can you tell me more about this 'explain' thing?

Comment: `explain <query>` gives you the execution plan of the query optimizer on the given query.  It's an absolutely fundamental tool, and no one should be allowed access to a production database without knowing about it.

Comment: @JackManey ok thanks, It tried adding 'explain' on the first line of the above query but all I got was 'keyword missing'.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, and what version?

Comment: @Ryan At this point I think the onus is on you to figure out how `explain` works and do more reading about query execution plans. This query is too complicated for us to just give you an answer if you aren't thoroughly educated on the subject.

Comment: @Ryan @JackManey: I think the syntax for Oracle's explain is `explain plan for <query>`. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: Are there indexes on check number on both db1.tbl_wip_hist_header and db1.tbl_payment_refund_header? Is there an index on payee number on db1.tbl_payment_checks? Does check number uniquely identify records on db1.tbl_payment_checks?

Comment: hire a competent database analyst/developer.  If you don't know about that 'explain' thingy, and if your company is serious about getting serious, then do the next logical step.

Comment: @tbone I'm a programmer, the DB folks are all on vacation this week :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quit with all the group by-s and subqueries. You can just use `left join`s and the `over` clause to get what you want:

```
select to_date(checks.payment_dte, 'YYYYMMDD') as payment_date,
       checks.run_number, 
       checks.check_nbr as check_number, 
       checks.check_amt as check_amount, 
       checks.payee_no as payee_number, 
       checks.loc as location, 
       checks.fac_state as facility_state, 
       checks.delta_usa_ind, 
       checks.payee_lnme as payee_last_name, 
       checks.payee_fnme as payee_first_name, 
       checks.payee_addr1 as payee_address1, 
       checks.payee_addr2 as payee_address2, 
       checks.payee_addr3 as payee_address3, 
       checks.payee_city, 
       checks.payee_st as payee_state, 
       to_char(checks.payee_zip, '00000') as payee_zip,
       to_char(checks.payee_zip4, '0000') as payee_zip4, 
       checks.payee_country_cde as payee_country_code,
       country.country_abbreviation as payee_country_code_description, 
       checks.maint_code as maintenance_code, 
       checks.mod_dte as mod_date, 
       checks.mod_op, 
       checks.payment_profile_id, 
       checks.bank_profile_id, 
       checks.parent_id,
       sum(nvl(h.total_net, 0) + nvl(r.refund_amount,0)*-1) over (partition by checks.check_nbr) as check_total
from 
    db1.tbl_payment_checks checks
    left join db1.tbl_wip_hist_header h on
        checks.check_nbr = h.check_nbr
    left join db1.tbl_payment_refund_header r on
        checks.check_nbr = r.check_nbr
    left join db1.tbl_code_country country on 
        checks.payee_country_cde = country.country
where 
    rownum < 10
    and checks.payee_no = '840932794'
order by payment_dte desc
```

That should run much faster.

Comment: down from over two minutes to 1.2 seconds, great job!

Answer (score 1):

Your query is slow because it's complicated. You're SELECTing from a SELECT that joins to a SELECT-UNION-SELECT. That's a lot of data that needs to be put into memory and re-queried over and over again. I think you need to consider rearchitecting this query from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and pull the join where you get check_total up into the select line.
I suspect it is doing join for all rows and the applying the where payee_no =.
If it is pulled up into the select then the query plan might get smarter.
This is just a sample of using a query in the select line

```
   select top sID, sParID, (select COUNT(*) from docSVsys as C where c.sParID = docSVsys.sParID) as famSize
   from docSVsys
```

With a real where clause when I was doing famSize with a join and a group by I was sometimes getting poor performance as it was calculating famSize for the entire table but the where only returned 10 rows.   On the other side if the query returned more then 1/4 of the rows in docSVsys then the join had better performance.

I am on MSSQL.  If this is not supported on Oracle sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is slow because of so many nested queries, you can do following things to improve query performance & maintainability-

1. Replace all nested subqueries with table variables and perform join on table variables. Insert return data of nested queries into table variables and use them in main query. It will increase the readability of your query, and you can find the segrigated scope of improvement in query.
2. Create primary key on table variables if possible by the nature of column, it will create clustered index on table variable and your joins will execute faster.
3. Check the execution plan, look for table scan and see if you can replace them with index seek by creating index on appropriate column.